# How to insert adsense on my ajax html5 based website template http://www.musicep.com/ ? I tried everything but nothing works

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, dynamic, adsense

I am trying to insert adsense ads in my blogger template ( doesn't matter the placement) and i can't do it so far. I've tried to insert the adsense code everywhere but nothing appears on the site. Why? I've tried to make a div with z-index 90000000 , but still my ads don't show up.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var addfbbox = function() { 
        $("#search").before("<span style='height: 62px; padding: 0; margin 0; position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 224px;'>........</span>"); }; 
    var checkSearchBar = function() { 
        if ($('#search').length > 0) { 
            addfbbox(); 
        } else { 
            setTimeout(checkSearchBar, 100); 
        } 
    }; 
    checkSearchBar(); 
});
```

Comment: You also might want to [check this out](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/50288?hl=en) since it seems to have a system built in to handle this.

Comment: Yes, that is working fine but i don't like to put my ads that way because i want to show only image ads and i don't have that option, plus i can't manage those ads. The only way how i could insert something in my template was to add a fixed facebook box with this code:

Answer (score 0):

A simple Google search reveals many results. Try one of these links.

- http://www.thesitewizard.com/revenue/adsense-in-blogger.shtml
- http://www.wikihow.com/Put-AdSense-Ads-on-a-Blogger-Blog

It would be my assumption that as a precaution or for some other reason, that blogger doesn't want you directly inserting your own adsense code, it appears you have to link your account in your profile.

Now if you are trying to bypass that you better look at their Terms of Use Statement. If it allows, this website shows a way to hack in your adsense code another way: www.probloggertricks.com/2013/02/how-to-add-adsense-inside-blogger-post_22.html

Comment: Thank you tremor but with this adsense implementation i lose money because i can't manage those ads and are most of the time low paying text ads. I want to put only image ads and position below post. Not only adsense, i can't insert anything in this template, i don't know how maybe :(

Comment: I've tried to put '<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>  
<div align="center">
 ad code </div>
</b:if>' above <data:post.body/> but no result